# Cannot install LibreOffice 3.6 from binary

Tags: installation, command-line, libreoffice, deb

So, I downloaded the main installer for LibreOffice 3.6 from the official website, because it hasn't yet arrived in PPA. Followed the instructions just as the ReadMe file suggests (navigate to the extracted folder from Terminal, and type "sudo dpkg -i *.deb"), but halfway through the installation, I get this error:

Setting up libreoffice3.6-calc (3.6.0.4-104) ...
Processing triggers for menu ...
In file "/usr/share/menu/introduceppa", at (or in the definition that ends at) line 4:
?package(introduceppa):needs="X11" section "Applications/File Management" title="Introduce PPA" command="/usr/bin/introduceppa.gambas" icon="/usr/share/pixmaps/introduceppa.png"
                                           ^
Expected: "="
Skipping file because of errors...

What does it mean? How do I fix it?

Comment: Did LibreOffice install properly besides this error, or did the entire installation fail? Can you post more of the output?

Comment: I'm not sure which output I need to post, but LibreOffice deb files unpacked successfully until one point. I found the conflicting application "Introduce PPA", and now I am trying to install with it removed.

Comment: Was Introduce PPA one of the .deb files extracted from the LibreOffice download? Seems a little strange that Introduce PPA would be included.

Comment: Ah, no, it wasn't. I "think" it might have been an application I installed a year or so ago when the OS wasn't upgraded yet. The app hasn't been showing in the menu, so I couldn't remember it was even installed. Anywho, i removed it, and now LO's installed fine. Thanks for your help, anyway!

Comment: Sweet! No problem!  :-)

Answer (score 2):

No worries, I solved my own problem. The path of the conflicting files indicates "menu", where I assume the commands or shortcuts are placed in the menu bar. I then realized that the application itself might be causing problems, so I just remove the app "Introduce PPA" from the software center (which only shows when you click "Show *** items").

It works beautifully now!